# Convert Spring Web MVC Application into JAR file and call all the functionalities in another Spring Web MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar

I have a Spring Web MVC application which I want to convert into JAR file and put it in another Spring Web MVC application's lib folder.I don't want to deploy the application of which i have made the JAR file.But I want to access all the functionalities from that JAR file in another Spring Web MVC application.Please help me if anyone knows the solution.

**Explanation  :**

1 .Application1(Spring Web MVC Application) -------->Export into JAR file---->app1.jar

2. Application2(Spring Web MVC Application)---->lib folder----->has app1.jar
3. app1.jar ----> has EmployeeController class which has

@RequestMapping(value="employeeList",method=RequestMethod.GET)

Need to call that in Application2 which will return me the view.

Note : Application1 which I converts into app1.jar that Application1 is not deployed in the server.It will run from the JAR file.

**Please help me.**